# How can I get the array outside the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#div").click(function(){
 $('#myselect').change(function() {
     var names = [];
     $('.checkbox input').each(function() {
           if(this.value != ''){
                 names.push(this.value);
                }
             });
     console.log(names);
  });
});
```

I need to use the `names` outside that function to use it on another function. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

```
$("#dropdown").change(function(){
  console.log(names);
});
```

`names` is an array.

Comment: What's your other function? What's the purpose you're trying to achieve?

Comment: And the reason you can't move the array to an outer scope is...? make them share the same scope by putting them inside the same ready handler and the array should be declared at top of the ready handler.

Comment: You are attaching the change event inside the click event, which means that you first have to click the #div element, then change the value in the #myselect control for the array to be filled. Is that really what you want, as what you do inside the change event doesn't depend on either the #div element or the #myselect control?

Comment: Also, are the elements that you target with `.checkbox input` checkboxes? In that case their value will never change due to user input. You would need to use the `checked` property to get their state.

Answer (score 3):

Define "names" outside the function...

```
var names = [];

    $('#myselect').change(function() {

         $('.checkbox input').each(function() {
               if(this.value != ''){
                     names.push(this.value);
                    }
                 });
         console.log(names);
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call the other function from that change-event handler. Defining the array outside of it would make no sense, it is bound to that event.

```
function gotNewNames(names) {
    // do something every time the value changes
}

$("#div").click(function(){
    $('#myselect').change(function() {
        var names = [];
        $('.checkbox input').each(function() {
            if(this.value != ''){
                names.push(this.value);
            }
        });
        gotNewNames(names);
    });
});
```

If you just need to be able to get the current values somewhere else, you should declare the variable in an higher scope, e.g. in the click handler:

```
$("#div").click(function(){
    var names;
    $('#myselect').change(function() {
        names = []; // don't forget to reset before filling
        $('.checkbox input').each(function() {
            if(this.value != ''){
                names.push(this.value);
            }
        });
    });
    $("#dropdown").change(function(){
        console.log(names);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Looks like the simplest solutions are often forgotten (talking about function parameters).

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this:

Please let me know if I missed anything.

Otherwise hope this helps,

**Code**

```
 var names = []; // Move the name array to outer scope 

 $("#div").click(function(){

    $('#myselect').change(function() {

        $('.checkbox input').each(function() {
            if(this.value != ''){
                names.push(this.value);
            }
        });
        console.log(names);
    });

    alert(names);
});
```

Comment: i try that one but it doesn't work for me... BTW thanks for your response!

Comment: No worries bruv, Hmm It should whorl, can you flick me your HTML I will make you a **demo** ? :)

Comment: i just edited my code above... i want to use that var name on other event

Comment: @OneBlueMidnight yep I noticed and updated my post accordingly :) all you need is to move your array to outer scope so that it is visible to others.